# CLion, запуск приложения в обычной консоли

Tags: windows-10, clion

CLion стандартно запускает приложение во встроенной консоли. Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы он автоматически запускал приложение в стандартной консоли (cmd)?

Windows10

Comment: Чем стандартная консоль не нравится?

Comment: @diraria криво выводит, да ещё и преподаватель требует)

Answer (score -1):

Shift+F9

debug режим в отдельном окошке.

Comment: Коллега, по поводу [отклонённой правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/328075): почитайте [тему на мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/), обратите особое внимание на случаи применения внутристрочного форматирования и полужирного начертания.