# Стандартная консоль в CLion

Tags: c++, clion

Как сделать запуск программы из CLion в стандартную консоль OS, а не в встроенную в CLion?

Comment: [Возможный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/716204/317064)

Comment: Просто на тот вопрос никто не ответил.

Comment: [Возможный дубликат x2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/719657/317064)

Comment: shift + F9 не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run -> Edit Configurations

Выбрать Run in external console[image]